# Clear file contents after uploading a file in modal popup

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am having some trouble in clearing file contents when  file upload is done via Ajax.Below is my modal popup html code,

```
            <div class="modal-header bg-blue">
                <div class="desktop_view">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"id="myModalLabel">Upload Document</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="mobile_view">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right bold" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"id="myModalLabel">Upload Document</h4>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="upload-container">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group fileinput-button">
                                <label class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 control-label">Select Your Document:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><input type="file" multiple name="file[]" accept="image/*" id="files" ></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="preview-container">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div id="dvPreview" class="preview-container"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <input type="submit"  value="Upload"  class = "btn btn-info" id= "save" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger myclose" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

After submitting the form,the previous image content still exists.I have tried below methods.

```
$('#myModalone').find('form')[0].reset();

$(function () {
  // Delegating to `document` just in case.
  $(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", "#myModalone", function () {

       //$('.modal-body').find('input').val('');
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
  });
});
```

It doesn't works.Please provide a solution.

Comment: those divs in JS don't exist in your HTML you provided. Which divs you want to clear?

Comment: You can do this simply by reloading the page after uploading the data through ajax. Or more complex, you ned to use jquery code like example remove elements. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: i prefer jquery code to remove elements

Comment: if i upload an image ,the array will be lik tis,  Array
(
    [0] => Lighthouse.jpg
)        and if i upload an image again previous image exists thereArray
(
    [0] => Lighthouse.jpg
    [1] => Tulips.jpg
)

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to the form and call form reset function as:

```
$("#formId")[0].reset()
// or
$("#formId").get(0).reset()
```

Also you can use js as:

```
document.getElementById('formId').reset();
```

To reset a div:

```
$('#div_id input[type="text"]').val('');

$('#div_id input[type="file"]').val('');
```

Find the working fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Safoora/Car52/174/